# Problema con elementos bloqueados en el cuadro de herramientas Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

Estoy usando Visual Studio 2019 y no se que habré tocado pero no tengo bloqueado los elementos del cuadro de herramientas.

Todas las herramientas están en gris y no puedo usarlas y las que están no puedo ver sus propiedades. ¿Cómo puedo resolver esto?

[image: captura de pantalla de VSCode con todas las herramientas desahbilitidas]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo actualice y se me puso así también.

Lo resolví yendo al panel de control > modificar > reparar.