# Elementos del cuadro de herramientas Visual Studio aparecen bloqueados

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto vacío CLR en donde cree formulario ".h", en este quiero añadir elementos (button, label, etc) del cuadro de herramientas, pero no me deja, ni arrastrando ni haciendo doble click. Las opciones aparecen como desactivadas como se muestra en la captura. Qué hago. He estado intentado resolverlo reestableciendo el cuadro de herramientas, desinstalando y volviendo a instalar, reparando la instalación y nada :c

Y si, lo estoy ejecutando como administrador
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/534866/problema-con-elementos-bloqueados-en-el-cuadro-de-herramientas-visual-studio